# Quantum Localization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, locality

**Hi every body,**

Could someone please give me clarification and explanation about localization, localization length and Quantum localization? All i know is that it has something to do with diffusion.

Thanks.

Comment: From the point of view of the quantum mechanics a system is localized when the volume occupied by the wave-packet is small. In such cases it is even possible to speak of the system as of a particle. But can't it be that you confuse between diffusion and dispersion? Dispersion means that a wave-packet, initially quite localized, spreads and as the time passes, becomes wider and wider.

Comment: can we define such thing for a system instead of just a single wave packet?like what people do in statistical mechanics and quantum chaos.actually i came across this concept when i was searching about quantum chaos.

Comment: I regret, but quantum chaos is not my domain

Comment: Maybe you mean Anderson localization? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization It can happen in random systems and in an energy region showing Anderson localization there is no diffusion. This phenomenon can in principle happen with other wave phenomena in random media such as light localisation or acoustic waves.